# Delphi SQL two tables

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe6

I have two tables in a database (Animal1 and Animal2). In animal1 there is a field called Animal_ID (1,2,3,4,5). In Animal2 there is also a field called Animal_ID (2,3,4).

I want to: Show only the Animal_ID of Animal1 which will exclude the numbers from Animal2
Example Output must be: 1,5 becuase 2,3,4 is in both tables.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

create a `TQuery` with the SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM Animal1 WHERE Animal1.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID from Animal2)
```

Where do you want to show them?

If you want to loop throu the Query     use

```
 with Unit.TQuery do begin
         First;
          while not EOF do begin
            // do your thing
             Next;
          end;

    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the exists clausule, which is much faster than "not in". Put the code above to Your Query1.SQL property.

```
select animal1.animal_id
from animal1
where not exists(select animal2.animal_id from animal2 where animal2.animal_id = animal1.animal_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, (which I think is the best from performance point of view) to use a `LEFT JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT Animal1.Animal_ID
FROM Animal1 LEFT JOIN Animal2 ON Animal1.Animal_ID = Animal2.Animal_ID
WHERE Animal2.Animal_ID IS NULL
```

For the best performance make sure Animal_ID are Primary Keys or Indexes (where duplicates are allowed)

*NOTE:* I assume you know about `TQuery`/`TDataSet` etc. (You did not specify that information, and also which DBMS you use...)